# How can you find the rate of convergence of an estimated parameter and how can the stabilizing transformation be derived?

Tags: probability, convergence, asymptotics

it would be great if someone could help me with the following problem:

We have given a scaled estimation error from which we know that $n^{1/2} (\hat{\theta}_0 - \theta_0) = a + b $ where $a \rightarrow_d N(0,\Sigma)$ and $|b| \rightarrow_p \infty $. Thus the transformation $n^{1/2} (\hat{\theta}_0 - \theta_0)$ has a degenerate distribution and can therefore not represent a stabilizing transformation.

In addition, we know that $a =\frac{1}{n^{1/2}} (\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n Z_i u_i ) $, where $E[Z_i u_i] = 0, Var(Z_i,u_i) = \Sigma_{zu}$. Furthermore, we know that $b= \frac{1}{n^{1/2}} (\sum_{i=1}^n Z_i (f_0(x_i) - \hat{f}_0(x_i)) $ and $n^{r_f}(f_0(Z_i)-\hat{f}_0(Z_i)) \rightarrow_d N(0,\Sigma_f)$ where $r_f< 1/2 $ denotes the rate of convergence of the estimator $\hat{f}_0(Z_i) $ but $E[\hat{f}_0(x_i)] \neq f_0(x_i)$.

I would be really grateful if someone could help me with the following questions:

1) How can you find the rate of convergence of the estimator $\hat{\theta}_0$ in this example?

2) How can you derive the stabilizing transformation of this estimator in the example?

Thank you for your help!